# Charting solutions for Yesod

Tags: haskell, charts, yesod

Currently I am using [hs-gchart](https://github.com/deepakjois/hs-gchart) do build charts to embed charts in my web application. I have seen that [tkyprof](https://github.com/maoe/tkyprof) uses [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/). What other charting solutions are being used with yesod? What are the pros and cons of these solutions?

Comment: Good question. I plan on using Chart, but will change my mind if someone comes up with something more useful here.

Comment: How do you integrate Chart? Create a custom handler to render an image?

Comment: I'm only requiring Yesod to display rendered charts. I have a management daemon that calls a separate program that renders the chart, after having called another program that starts the process that generates chart data.

Answer (score 2):

[hledger-web](http://demo.hledger.org/register?q=inacct%3Aassets%3Abank%3Achequing) uses [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). Pro: very easy, featureful, supported, no dependence on google or net access, offloads rendering work to clients, probably makes your haskell build life much easier (no need for GTK). Con: not as well integrated with your app as a haskell solution would be.

There is also [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) which is probably the flashiest js charting lib and free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

I think d3.js should also be mentioned. There is a DSL approach to d3js in Haskell.